# How to use datastore key as Channel API client id?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, channel-api

I do the following:

```
user = User()
...
user.put()
client_id = user.key() # value like agpkZXZ-Y3Njb3JlcgoLEgRVc2VyGAkM

token = channel.create_channel(client_id)
```

and I am getting `InvalidChannelClientIdError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client_id` is a `Key`, `create_channel(..)` expects a string.

Here is [what docs say](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/exceptions.html) about `InvalidChannelClientIdError`:

```
The specified Client ID is malformed. Client IDs must be UTF-8 or ASCII strings 
and should be less than 64 characters.
```

You could potentially use `key.name()` if your user id is generated by you and is sufficiently unique. If User id is generated by Datastore, then it is a short integer number like 1001, 2001, etc, and is not sufficiently unique.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I can do `channel.create_channel(str(client_id))`.

Comment: Just make sure that `channel_id` you provide is sufficiently unique.